# show/hide item using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have developed a 3D model using JavaScript.

I need to show/hide a specific item in the model using a checkbox.

In the html file the checkbox has implemented.

```
<div id= "shower" class="row-shower" /div>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-shower" /> 
<label for="show-shower"> show/hide shower </label>
```

In the JS file, called the function:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('shower'),
  showshower = document.getElementById("show-shower");
  showshower.checked = true;
  showshower.onchange = function() {
    elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'cubicle' : 'none';
  };
  showshower.onchange();
```

CSS code:

```
.cubicle {
    display:block;
}

.hideCubicle {
   display:none;
}
```

The current issue I'm facing is when click the show/hide checkbox the whole model is gone. I just need the shower to be disappear. Not the whole model.

Any suggestion how to perform this?

Comment: first, you have an unclosed/malformed div tag here: `<div id= "shower" class="row-shower" /div>`

Comment: Have you tried changing classes instead of the display attribute?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('shower');
 showshower = document.getElementById("show-shower");

 showshower.onchange = function ()
 {
     elem.classList = this.checked ? 'cubicle' : 'hideCubicle';
 };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kan1r80

Answer (score 0):

You can change try code see

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".show-content").hide();
        $('.check').change(function() {
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $(".show-content").show(); 
         }
         else{
          $(".show-content").hide(); 
         }
                
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Show/Hide</label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="check">
 <div class="show-content">
  I have developed a 3D model using JavaScript.

  I need to show/hide a specific item in the model using a checkbox.

  In the html file the checkbox has implemented.

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I just add the following code to the JS file.

> ```
> if(checked){
>                 pSpec.cubicle.visible=false;
>
>
>                 console.log("hide");
>             }
> else
>           {
>                 pSpec.cubicle.visible=true;
>
>
>                 console.log("show");
>             }
> ```

You might wonder where the pSpec variable come from. That's the variable which I used to create partitions in the model. I did not share the whole code because it is lot of coding.